# Converter string em array

Tags: php, mysql, string

Galera eu recebo dados da minha database que vem dessa forma `1,2,3,4,5` e preciso rodar cada numero, por que cada numero é um ID de usuario e eu quero que ele exiba cada um separadamente sem virgula nem nada,eu tentei dar foreach mas nao consegui, como faco?

Comment: Deu certo a resposta para você Vinicius?

Comment: Sim! consegui executar minha tarefa, desculpe nao atualizar a questao ainda..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Assim:***

```
<?php     
    $numeros = '1,2,3,4,5';
    $num = explode(',', $numeros);
    foreach($num as $n){
       echo $n;
       echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/JDii6W)