# como faço para pega uma linha de um campo que não tem delimitações e quebrar em array?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho o código que pega de um campo uma string no exemplo abaixo:

> material planta peça vazo luz

Essa string não tem delimitações e ainda por cima, como dá pra ver, as palavras da string que preciso quebrar tem caracteres distintos executando meu código abaixo a string aparece assim:

> material plantape çavazolu z

a string acima é só um exemplo do problema do meu código, alguém sabe como resolver isso?

```
$text = $_POST["text"];
$plant = $_POST["combox"];

    mysql_query("Delete from flex_report.tab_mtm_ativos where planta = '$plant'");

    $count = strlen($text);

    for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++){
        if(strstr($text,"-")){
            $replace = str_replace("-","",$text);   
            $novaString = chunk_split($replace,12,".");
        }else{
            $novaString = chunk_split($text,9,".");
        }
    }

    //quebra array em string
    $bat = explode('.',$novaString);
    print_r($bat)."<br>";
```

preciso que a string se divida:

```
string = material planta peça luz chocolate
```

eu quero quebra essa string acima como esta no exemplo abaixo:

string divida

> 0 => material
>   1 => planta
>   2 => peça
>   3 => luz
>   4 => chocolate

é isso que eu preciso mais com o codigo que eu fiz sai asssim

> 0 => material
>   1 => plantape
>   2 => çaluzcho
>   3 => colate

Comment: Se você não explicar o que quer, fica dificil de ajudarmos. Qual é o resultado que você quer obter, como é que a saída tem que ficar? Você quer pegar palavra por palavra, letra por letra ou o quê? E como vai usar a saída?

Comment: como eu não conseguir fazer o explode com espaço, eu coloquei um "." para delimitar a string e joguei dentro dessa variavel

Comment: O problema é que a tua contagem está delimitando o número de caracteres da string.
8 caracateres em cada item.

Faz assim:
$palavras = explode(" ", $text);
$count = count($palavras);

Comment: Veja se é isso, `$arr = explode(' ','material planta peça vazo luz') print_r($arr);`

Comment: conseguir resolver, usei a função json_encode para delimitar \n\r e depois fiz um explode quebrando com \n\r

Comment: estou curioso para saber como fez o json_encode() adicionar quebras de linha

Comment: Na verdade você não resolveu, você fez outra gambiarra no lugar da original. A solução correta é a que o @rray mencionou, e a pergunta depois da edição é uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22063/ (só muda o delimitador)

Answer (score 1):

Na string que informou há um delimitador, o espaço.

Basta apenas “explodir” os espaços.

```
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
```